# Pegar a última mensagem de uma conversa (GROUP BY)

Tags: mysql, query, group-by, order-by

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT 
    cp_mensagem.mensagem, 
    cp_mensagem.dh_envio, 
    cp_projeto.id as id_projeto, 
    cp_projeto.nome as nome_projeto, 
    cp_pessoa.id as id_freelancer, 
    cp_pessoa.nome as nome_freelancer 
FROM cp_mensagem 
    JOIN cp_projeto ON (cp_projeto.id = cp_mensagem.id_projeto) 
    JOIN cp_pessoa ON (cp_pessoa.id = cp_mensagem.id_freelancer) 
WHERE cp_pessoa.id = 6 AND cp_mensagem.dh_visualizacao is NULL AND cp_mensagem.id_tipo_remetente = 1 
ORDER BY cp_mensagem.dh_envio DESC
```

Essa query traz o seguinte resultado:

```
mensagem    |   dh_envio                |   id_projeto  |   nome_projeto    |   id_freelancer   |   nome_freelancer
Olá...      |   2014-04-22 11:51:41     |   2           |   WebSite         |   6               |   José
Oi...       |   2014-04-19 00:00:00     |   2           |   WebSite         |   6               |   José
```

Para não repetir o id_projeto e id_freelancer eu uso o GROUP BY, desta forma:

```
SELECT 
        cp_mensagem.mensagem, 
        cp_mensagem.dh_envio, 
        cp_projeto.id as id_projeto, 
        cp_projeto.nome as nome_projeto, 
        cp_pessoa.id as id_freelancer, 
        cp_pessoa.nome as nome_freelancer 
    FROM cp_mensagem 
        JOIN cp_projeto ON (cp_projeto.id = cp_mensagem.id_projeto) 
        JOIN cp_pessoa ON (cp_pessoa.id = cp_mensagem.id_freelancer) 
    WHERE cp_pessoa.id = 6 AND cp_mensagem.dh_visualizacao is NULL AND cp_mensagem.id_tipo_remetente = 1 
GROUP BY cp_mensagem.id_projeto, cp_mensagem.id_freelancer
    ORDER BY cp_mensagem.dh_envio DESC
```

Essa query me traz o seguinte resultado:

```
mensagem    |   dh_envio                |   id_projeto  |   nome_projeto    |   id_freelancer   |   nome_freelancer
Oi...       |   2014-04-19 00:00:00     |   2           |   WebSite         |   6               |   José
```

Eu estou ordenando pelo dh_envio, porem ela ainda me traz a mensagem com a data mais antiga, como eu faço para a query me trazer a última mensagem do grupo (id_projeto/id_freelancer)?

Comment: Na condição Utilizas o MAX:

Comment: Um pouco do schema ajudaria também

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria um `inner join` com uma `sub query`:

```
Select a.*
From cp_mensagem a
Join ( SELECT id_projeto, id_freelancer, max(cp_mensagem.dh_envio) as dh_envio
    FROM cp_mensagem 
    WHERE id_pessoa = 6 
AND dh_visualizacao is NULL 
AND id_tipo_remetente = 1 
GROUP BY cp_mensagem.id_projeto, cp_mensagem.id_freelancer) b on a.id_projeto =b.id_projeto
And a.id_freelancer = b.id_freelancer
And a.dh_envio = b.dh_envio
And a.dh_visualizacao is NULL
```