# Como obter o valor de uma coluna correspondente ao máximo de outra coluna?

Tags: sql, group-by

Possuo uma tabela com as colunas `codigo`, `data` e `valor`. Gostaria de obter, para cada código, o valor correspondente à data mais recente. De que maneiras isso pode ser feito? E se há mais de uma, qual é a mais eficiente. Exemplo:

```
minha_tabela
codigo        data        valor
-------------------------------
  1        2014-01-01      10
  1        2014-01-02      20
  2        2014-01-03      30
  2        2014-01-04      40
  2        2014-01-05      50
  3        2014-01-06      60
```

Resultado esperado:

```
codigo        data        valor
-------------------------------
  1        2014-01-02      20
  2        2014-01-05      50
  3        2014-01-06      60
```

Obter a data mais recente é fácil: basta fazer um `group by` com agregação `max`. O problema está em obter o valor correspondente a essa data:

```
select t.codigo as codigo, max(t.data) as data, ??? as valor
from minha_tabela t
group by t.codigo;
```

Gostaria de uma solução que funcionasse no SQL "standard", sem depender de características particulares de nenhum SGBD específico.

Comment: Nota: essa é uma dúvida minha comum e recorrente, e sinto falta de uma pergunta "canônica" fácil de encontrar. Há outras perguntas semelhantes ([exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27264/215), [exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13989/215)) mas que estão meio que "escondidas" sob outros aspectos, por isso quis fazer uma que vai "direto ao ponto".

Comment: Não estou a perceber... `??? == t.valor` é isso?

Comment: @JorgeB. Isso foi só uma indicação de que eu não sei o que fazer para descobrir o valor certo. Não posso usar `t.valor` pois ele não está presente na cláusula `group by`. Não posso usar `max(t.valor)` pois senão ele iria pegar o valor máximo - e não o valor da data máxima. Etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A melhor alternativa que me passa pela cabeça é

```
select m.*
  from minha_tabela m
 inner join (
       select codigo, max(data) data
         from minha_tabela
        group by codigo) x
 using(codigo, data);
```

que é o mesmo que

```
select m.*
  from minha_tabela m
 inner join (
       select codigo, max(data) data
         from minha_tabela
        group by codigo) x
    on m.codigo=x.codigo and m.data=x.data;
```

o resultado será o mesmo que o da resposta do @Motta porem não terá o overhead de executar o *sub-select* na clausula `where` para cada registro.

Segue exemplo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c438e/32).

Comment: Seria o caso de comparar os 3 Planos de Execuções !!

Answer (score 6):

```
select  *
from tabela t1
where data = (select max(t2.data)
              from tabela t2
              where t2.codigo = t1.codigo)
```

Uma solução usando subselect (existem outras)

Comment: Contanto que não existam duas linhas com o mesmo código e a mesma data (o que é razoável de se assumir), essa é uma boa solução. +1

Comment: @mgibsonbr de fato.

Answer (score 0):

Se for o que eu estou pensando, 
eu consegui fazer da seguinte forma:

```
select * from minha_tabela
where valor = (select max(valor) from minha_tabela);
```

Comment: Rafael, bem-vindo ao site. Repare que sua sugestão é basicamente o que o Motta já tinha dito.

Comment: Não , a minha é a maior data de uma chave a dele o maior valor da tabela, casos diferentes ainda que ligeiramente.