# Ajuda com select em MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

[image: **modelo logico do meu banco de dados**]

Gostaria de saber como eu faco para listar para cada cidade o clientes mais antigo, tentei diversos comandos mas sem sucesso.
Gostaria que citasse de maneira automatica. Abaixo alguns comandos que usei, porem não obtive o resultado esperado.

select distinct  endereco,nome from cliente order by anoIngresso asc;

com esse comando ele me retorna todos os endereços, o que eu queria é que para a cidade A eu só obtivesse o cliente mais antido dela e assim por diante.

Exemplo:

cidade A -- cliente joao

Cidade B -- cliente maria

cidade C -- cliente jose

.....

Agradeço se alguem puder me ajudar...

Comment: Fala aí, Mairon! Blz?! Só uma dica: Poste a estrutura da sua tabela pra facilitar pra quem for te ajudar. Outra coisa que agiliza bastante é postar alguns registros tb. SEMPRE como TEXTO. Não como imagem, blz?!

Comment: Se possível, edite a pergunta e coloque qual a forma que você está tentando e não está conseguindo obter o resultado esperado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode dar um *select* ordenando pelas duas colunas que você deseja usar como critério. Se eu tiver compreendido da forma correta, você deseja dar esse *select* na tabela `Cliente`. Desse modo, ficaria assim:

```
SELECT cidade, nome
FROM Cliente
ORDER BY anoIngresso ASC;
```

Para ter certeza que o campo `anoIngresso` é da tabela `Cliente`, você pode tentar assim:

```
SELECT cidade, nome
FROM Cliente
ORDER BY Cliente.anoIngresso ASC;
```

Em ambos os casos, ele irá pegar (e mostrar) os campos `cidade` e `nome`, ordenando-os pelo campo `anoIngresso`, ou seja, do mais antigo, ao mais recente.

E se você quiser estabelecer um limite para até um ano específico, pode adicionar o `WHERE` dessa forma:

```
SELECT cidade, nome
FROM Cliente
ORDER BY anoIngresso ASC
WHERE anoIngresso < 2000;
```

Ou seja, mostrar a `cidade` e o `nome` dos clientes que ingressaram antes do ano 2000, ordenando-os pelo próprio `anoIngresso`.

**[Editado]**

O "problema" do `SELECT DISTINCT` com dois campos, é que ele leva em consideração, obviamente, os dois campos. Ou seja, se tenho uma tabela `Funcionarios` dessa forma:

```
id   |   nome   |     cidade       | idade
1    |  João    |  Rio de Janeiro  |   30
2    |  Maria   |  Rio de Janeiro  |   27
3    |  João    |  São Paulo       |   28
```

E então executar:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cidade, nome FROM Funcionarios ORDER BY idade ASC;
```

Irá retornar:

```
    cidade     | nome
Rio de Janeiro | Maria
São Paulo      | João
Rio de Janeiro | João
```

Pois, *"Rio de Janeiro e Maria"* e *"Rio de Janeiro e João"* são **distintos**; assim como também *"São Paulo e João"* e *"Rio de Janeiro e João"* são **distintos**.

Então, se você deseja que haja somente um cliente para cada cidade, acho que você terá que manipular os dados após a consulta, pois, somente através do MySQL (até onde eu sabia) não é possível obter o resultado desejado.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Pelo que entendi, ele quer retornar apenas um cliente de cada cidade. Justamente o mais antigo... (sic) - "*Exemplo: cidade A -- cliente joao / Cidade B -- cliente maria / cidade C -- cliente jose*"

Comment: `para cada cidade os clientes mais antigos`

Comment: A própria pergunta entra em contradição com o exemplo (falta concordância). Acho que o exemplo foi mais específico, como mencionei...

Comment: Boa noite Gustavo, acabei não colocando na pergunta, o fato é que quero selecionar somente o cliente mais antigo de cada cidade e não a lista completa, estava tentando colocar o distinct depois do select porém com dois campos não me retorna o resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar o problema deve rodar o seguinte comando

```
select * from cliente where cidade = [ entre " " coloque o nome da cidade ] ORDER BY anoIngresso DESC LIMIT [ aqui você coloca o quanto que deseja que apareça ]
```

Answer (score 0):

> como eu faco para listar para cada cidade o clientes mais antigo

Como não foi postado a estrutura da sua tabela, vou **sugerir** a seguinte:

```
CREATE DATABASE `teste` DEFAULT CHARSET `utf8` DEFAULT COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci`;
USE `teste`;
CREATE TABLE `clientes` (
    `idCliente` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `endereco` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cidade` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `anoIngresso` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY(`idCliente`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

A fim de testar, vou inserir alguns registros. Repare que o cliente que deve ser retornado contém um asterisco ao final do nome:

```
INSERT INTO `clientes` (`nome`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `anoIngresso`) VALUES
    ('João *', 'Rua A', 'Rio de Janeiro', 1992),
    ('José', 'Rua D', 'Rio de Janeiro', 1995),
    ('Joaquim', 'Rua H', 'Rio de Janeiro', 1997),
    ('Maria', 'Rua H', 'São Paulo', 2000),
    ('Janete', 'Rua 1', 'São Paulo', 1995),
    ('Malaquias *', 'Rua E', 'São Paulo', 1992),
    ('Zeca *', 'Rua X', 'Curitiba', 1997),
    ('Inácio', 'PF', 'Curitiba', 2018);
```

Por fim, vamos executar a ***query*-solução**:

```
SELECT `cl`.*
    FROM `clientes` AS `cl`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `cidade`, MIN(`anoIngresso`) AS `menorAno`
    FROM `clientes`
    GROUP BY `cidade`
) AS `cd`
    ON `cl`.`cidade` = `cd`.`cidade` and `cl`.`anoIngresso` = `cd`.`menorAno`;
```

Que retorna:

```
+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------+-------------+
| idCliente | nome        | endereco | cidade         | anoIngresso |
+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------+-------------+
|         1 | João *      | Rua A    | Rio de Janeiro |        1992 |
|         6 | Malaquias * | Rua E    | São Paulo      |        1992 |
|         7 | Zeca *      | Rua X    | Curitiba       |        1997 |
+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

> Exemplo:
>
> cidade A -- cliente joao
>
> Cidade B -- cliente maria
>
> cidade C -- cliente jose

Basta alterar o filtro da *query*:

```
SELECT `cl`.`cidade`, `cl`.`nome`
    FROM `clientes` AS `cl`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `cidade`, MIN(`anoIngresso`) AS `menorAno`
    FROM `clientes`
    GROUP BY `cidade`
) AS `cd`
    ON `cl`.`cidade` = `cd`.`cidade` and `cl`.`anoIngresso` = `cd`.`menorAno`;
```

Que retorna:

```
+----------------+-------------+
| cidade         | nome        |
+----------------+-------------+
| Rio de Janeiro | João *      |
| São Paulo      | Malaquias * |
| Curitiba       | Zeca *      |
+----------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Uma pergunta semelhante foi solucionada aqui:

> [SOpt - Como obter o valor de uma coluna correspondente ao máximo de outra coluna?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27682/45810)